# dbt run with materialized: table does not drop and recreate table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, dbt

I'm using dbt-sqlserver and I have created a model and configured it to materialized: table.

The first run created the table with no issue but in the second run I get this error.

When searching for a relation, dbt found an approximate match. Instead of guessing which relation to use, dbt will move on. Please delete db.dbo.x or rename it to be less ambiguous.

Searched for: db.dbo.x

Found: db.dbo.x

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command with the appropriate flag dbt run -f